# Qt set line edit text to link clicked link?

Tags: qt, hyperlink

Using this:

```
void MainWindow::on_webView_linkClicked(const QUrl &arg1)
{

}
```

How can I set a `lineEdit` to the link text? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have a link like the following ...

```
<a href="foo.html">bar</a>
```

.. and you want to get the value "bar." If that's what you are trying to do, you can't from that method. A few options, depending on how much control you have over the page:

- Embed the text of the hyperlink into the URL and extract it. Something like: `<a href="foo.html?text=bar">bar</a>`
- If you are generating these links yourself, and there is a one-to-one relationship between URL and text, set up a map from url to text and look up the text in the map.

Comment: No, I was looking to get the url(just messing around making a web browser) but I got it now! Thanks anyways! :)